# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4517 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using BLE esp32 to get data from sensors but when I want to calibrate by getting data from the BLE device it gives me this error on Stream Builder I have used in the Device Setting up screen. A soon as I press Configuration it moves to the device set up page. I want is that, until I get value 1 from BLE it should keep on showing this screen

[image: device set up page]

and once 1 comes it should go to the other screen to show a message and picture done like this and then automatically moves to Homepage after 2 seconds.

[image: device set up done page]

But it shows the bottom overflowed with the error msg "Bluetooth is not active", how can I avoid that? and jump for the next page? BLE is active as well since I checked the values were coming on another screen, but it is not happening on this screen for the connected device. Also the device done page it is not even going to Homescreen
I am new to FLutter that's why i have no idea what i should do with it.

Code for Device Set up Screen:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:epicare/ConfDeviceDone.dart';
import 'package:epicare/ConfigurationScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

import 'Homepage.dart';

class ConfDeviceSet extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConfDeviceSet({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  @override
  _ConfDeviceSetState createState() => _ConfDeviceSetState();
}

class _ConfDeviceSetState extends State<ConfDeviceSet> {
  // BLE
  final String SERVICE_UUID = "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b";
  //final String SERVICE_UUID = "0365a300-8d69-4066-80c7-554298a6ec5e";
  //final String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "cf01c075-cb75-4dea-819e-2a79dd466bcb";
  final String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8";
  bool isReady;
  Stream<List<int>> stream;
  List<int> lastValue;
  List<double> traceDust = List();
  @override
  void initState() {
    isReady = false;
    discoverServices();
  }

  discoverServices() async {
    List<BluetoothService> services = await widget.device.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      if (service.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID) {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
            characteristic.setNotifyValue(!characteristic.isNotifying);
            stream = characteristic.value;
            //print(stream);
            lastValue = characteristic.lastValue;
            //print(lastValue);

            setState(() {
              isReady = true;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  _dataParser(List<int> data) {
    var value = Uint8List.fromList(data);
    print("stream.value: $value"); // stream.value: [33]
    var hr = ByteData.sublistView(value, 0, 1);
    print("Heart rate: ${hr.getUint8(0)}");
    return hr.getUint8(0); // Heart rate: 33
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Configuration",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return ConfigurationScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              'Device setting up...',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 17,
                color: const Color(0xa8000000),
                height: 1.3333333333333333,
              ),
              textHeightBehavior:
                  TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 120),
            child: const SpinKitFadingCircle(
              color: const Color(0xffF1C40E),
              size: 200,
            ),
          ),
          StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
            stream: stream,
            initialData: lastValue,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
              var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data);
              if (currentValue == 1) {
                print("Test Conf 1");
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return ConfDeviceDone(
                        device: widget.device,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code for Device Done screen

```
import 'package:epicare/Homepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

import 'ConfigurationScreen.dart';

class ConfDeviceDone extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConfDeviceDone({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  @override
  _ConfDeviceDoneState createState() => _ConfDeviceDoneState();
}

class _ConfDeviceDoneState extends State<ConfDeviceDone> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // isReady = false;
    // discoverServices();
    var d = Duration(seconds: 2);
    // delayed 5 seconds to next page
    Future.delayed(d, () {
      // to next page and close this page
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return Homepage(device: widget.device);
          },
        ),
            (route) => false,
      );
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Configuration",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              'Device Configured Successfully!',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 15,
                color: const Color(0xa8000000),
                height: 1.3333333333333333,
              ),
              textHeightBehavior:
                  TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 120),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/green-tick.gif'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: error is because of streambuilder  you are not returning widget   . Yes you are returning widget when if condition is satisfied  implement a else condition also

Comment: i used else condition before but it was giving the same error so i removed it

Comment: Also, is it because of the Stream builder the other screen isn't jumping to the Homepage after 2 secs?

Comment: as I can see and you told  yes stream builder  causing it but about returning back to homescreen I cannot say

Comment: once try to just show a widget in streambuilder rather than pushing to check it is causing problem or not

Comment: The problem is with the check statement for current Value, i can;t resolve it

Comment: What causing problem in current value ?

Comment: My current Value is getting first 0 values and then 1, if 1 comes it should show Configuration DOne activity but it is not happening. I don't know why is it not jumping to next activity

Comment: Even i have applied timer to Configuration done page but it is not even jumping to Homepage once timer ends